# Unexpected token function for koa-bodyparser

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, koa

I am trying to use babel for compilation of my KOA code.But when I run my code, it gives me below error:

```
return async function bodyParser(ctx, next) {
           ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function)
```

Node version : 6.10.3

Comment: Are you sure that babel has processed this?

Comment: I think for this node 7.6+ is required

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Node version that's less than 7.6 with Koa v1, you need to install the right version of `koa-bodyparser`. Try doing:

```
npm install koa-bodyparser@2
```

Version 2 of `koa-bodyparser` doesn't use `async` functions. This is described at the bottom in the [README](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser) of the module.

Comment: Ya..I also found the same solution and it worked for me. Thanks.